# Retrieving URI template used in RestTemplate call from ClientHttpRequestInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm using `RestTemplate` to call an external resource using `GET` where the URI is https://external.com/resource/{resourceID}.

Accordingly, my `RestTemplate` calls looks like the following:

`restTemplate.getForObject("https://external.com/resource/{resourceID}", String.class, uriMapObject)`

Where `uriMapObject` is a map containing the ID variable.

I have also set a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for my `RestTemplate` where the interceptor's function is to create a log item for that call and send it to ElasticSearch for logging.

```
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> reqHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        try{
            // getPath() already contains the URI variable
            String uri = httpRequest.getURI().getPath(); 

        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        }

.....
        return response;
    }
```

The issue is that within the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` method, I'm unable to access the original URI template used to derive the actual URL to call. I can only access the actual URL from the `HttpRequest` object which already has a unique identifier in it which in turn makes it impossible to aggregate all calls to https://external.com/resource/{resourceID} as a single pattern in Elastic.

Is there some way where I can get the URI template from within the interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

URI template expansion is specified by the [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)'s [`UriTemplateHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplateHandler.html).  You can customize the behavior of this by calling [`RestTemplate#setUriTemplateHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setUriTemplateHandler-org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplateHandler-), specifying your own implementation.

I would suggest creating a delegate object for a UriTemplateHandler, and wrapping what is set by default on the `RestTemplate`.

```
class LoggingUriTemplateHandler implements UriTemplateHandler {
    private UriTemplateHandler delegate;

    LoggingUriTemplateHandler(final UriTemplateHandler delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public URI expand(final String template, final Map<String, ?> vars) {
        //log template here
        return this.delegate.expand(template, vars);
    }

    public URI expand(final String template, final Object... vars) {
        //log template here
        return this.delegate.expand(template, vars);
    }
}
```